# python code won't print anything when it is run

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to make something that takes all of my discord user tokens in tokens.txt and then tells me if they are valid user tokens. However, it never prints anything and just quits. If anyone knows how to fix this please let me know.

```
import requests
    
with open("tokens.txt","r+") as f:
    for line in f:
        token=line.strip("\n")
        headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'authorization': token}
        url = "https://discordapp.com/api/v6/users/@me/library"
        if r.status_code == 200:
            print(token+" is valid")
        else:
            print("invalid token found~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
```

I have tried to do this several times

```
$ python3 tokenfilter.py
$ python3 tokenfilter.py
$
```

Comment: `r` is never defined anywhere; I'm assuming you had something like `r = requests.get(url,headers=headers)`?

Comment: where is the request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't make any request. You should add something like:

```py
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please double check that your text file has some text in it.

Also try

import sys

sys.stdout.flush()

There are some cases in python where the output is send to the buffer but buffer is not printed/emptied.

If first check is true then second should work

Answer (score -1):

```
import requests
    
with open("tokens.txt","r+") as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        token=line.strip("\n")
        headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'authorization': token}
        url = "https://discordapp.com/api/v6/users/@me/library"
        if r.status_code == 200:
            print(token+" is valid")
        else:
            print("invalid token found~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
```